# Vue 3 Component not displaying in Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have tried everything I can think of but despite having no build errors I cannot get Vue components to load in my very simple project. I do not understand why but I just get a blank page when trying to view the page with Laravel serve.

##### `welcome.blade.php`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
        <title>Laravel</title>
    
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
    </head> 
    <body class="antialiased">
        <div id='app'>
            <Home />
        </div>
    
        <script scr="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### `app.js`

```
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp } from 'vue'

import Home from './components/Home.vue';

const app = createApp({});

app.component('home', Home);

app.mount('#app');
```

#### `Home.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1> WELCOME </h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

#### `webpack.mix.js`

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ]);
```

Comment: I am not sure if it will help, but instead of `div id='app'` do `div id="app"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*i cant comment because of my score, sorry to have to do it like an awnser..*

---

are you sure that `app.component('home', Home);` line is the right way to import a comp?
because from what i find, this would be the

```
Vue.component('home', require('./components/Home.vue').default);
```

whould be the way.

Comment: tried it that way and get the same issue, no errors but nothing displays

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to change the tag in your blade from `<Home />`to `<home />` ?
As wrote by another user before you must add .default in your row where you import the component

Comment: yeah I tried that no luck, I must just be doing something really stupid wrong or have an issue with how the project is set up

Comment: Ok I'm reviewed another time your code.
I can suggest you to listen @matiaslauriti that say you to change your html from `div=' to div="`
In addition to that I suggest you to change your app.js file as below:
`require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp } from 'vue';

import Home from './components/Home.vue';

createApp(Home).mount('#app');`

Answer (score 0):

basically needed to add some of what I was adding to app.js to the .vue file to get it working such as the import from vue.

Comment: Could you share what you did exactly to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but from what I see, you did not receive a satisfactory response/solution for your problem yet.

I had the same problem/a very similar upgrading a very old Laravel project (started about 9 years ago on an old Laravel version) from AngularJS to Vue3: Despite all attempts and a very barebone setup, the Vue root app component did not load.

The solution was to ensure that the "main" app.js file was being loaded using the script defer tag. Thus, in your blade file, change:

```
<script scr="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

to

```
<script defer src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

As a sidenote, there is a typo in this line in your original question: Change script **scr** to script **src** :-)